# jQuery, toggle()

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, show

My page has dynamic divs and within them I want to toggle between two divs. I need to preserve the original value of the div so this may be the wrong approach

Here's my code thus far, I cannot seem to get it going.

```
$(".change").live("click", function() {
  var changeDiv = $(this).parents(".changeContainer").find(".changeDiv");
  changeDiv.toggle();
  changeDiv.html(changeDiv.html() == '<input type='text' />' ? 'Original Value of the DIV' : '<input type='text' />');
}


<div class="changeContainer">
   <div class="changeDiv">Basketball - <a href="#" class="change">Change Sport</a>   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try changeDiv.toggle() instead of $(changeDiv()).toggle()

Comment: How do I preserve the original value?

Comment: use a variable in the div? like <div keep="value"> and in the function use changeDiv.attr("keep") = value. by head, may be bas syntax btw.

Comment: Hmm, getting closer I think. I updated the code, the toggle just seems to turn the div blank.

Comment: Eeh, that's what toggle is supposed to do : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ . Can you explain what you actually want  to achieve?

Comment: Yep, when a user clicks Change sport, I want to replace the content of the div with an input box with a "Cancel Change" link, which reverts back to the original.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link, rather than comments, to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a toggle, just use standard show/hide.  Put in both divs, have one of them start with `style="display:hidden"` and then use jquery .hide() and .show() on the appropriate divs to swap between them.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I actually just came to this on my own, but will credit you with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be more in the line of

```
$(".change").live("click", function() {
  var changeDiv = $(this).parents(".changeContainer").find(".changeDiv");

  if(changeDiv.hasClass('orig') {
       orig_html = changeDiv.html();
       changeDiv.html('<input type='text' />');
  else
       changeDiv.html(orig_html);
  }
  changeDiv.toggleClass('orig');
}
```

and have a global var orig_html;
Be aware, I did not test the code.